# Is any one else experiencing issues with the new action links

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph

I followed the guide on creating action links here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/
However, when I'm testing them with a new facebook app that I created it is not displaying the test action link. Is there some secret to making these work that is not included in the guide, or am I just rather unlucky?

Comment: I figured it out after re-reading and triple-checking everything. I used http instead of https for the "Action Link Url" field. It is odd that they do not throw any errors when saving since it silently shuts down the action links.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse, non-https action links should still be visible to developers, with an error message shown on the link itself.

Comment: That is probably why I was using the http based link at first. However, I could not get the action link to show up until I switched to https. (At the time I was logged in as an app Administrator, maybe I needed to demote myself to just a Developer) Regardless, I'm fine with just using https. Thanks though for your input.